# PHP encode query-string

Tags: php, encoding, get

I have a link with a query-string:

`/mycontroller/?var1=aaa&var2=bbb`

as I want the browsers back-button to work without that `reload page`-syndrom, I have to send the data via GET.

But I want to encode/encrypt the GET-string, so the user doesn't see, what variables are sent in it.

how could this be done? what encoding/encryption would be good for this?

Comment: How "strong" do you want this protection to be?  That is, what is the actual problem being solved here?  Also, what systems are performing the encryption/decryption?  Would you be encrypting client-side and decrypting server-side?  Or something else?  You can essentially have a single query string key/value where the value is a serialized and obscured set of data (within reasonable size limits).  But whether or not that's meaningful or helpful depends more on what you're really trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @David .. hi, thanks for the quick response. the en/decryption would have to be be both, client and serverside. the grade of "protection" is not so high, I simply dont want the normal user to see, that his data is sent in the GET-string

Comment: Well, the user would see that *some* data is being sent.  And the user can see any data which exists client-side.  If the user cares to, he/she could still view and modify this information regardless of any encryption used.

Comment: yes, it is not so tragic that the user sees, that data is beeing sent.. also, the data that is client-side is not tragic.. I simply want the get-string to be unreadable for the 'normal' user

Comment: In that case while I don't have an exact answer it would appear that this concept has been asked/discussed in the past as well.  May or may not be an *exact* duplicate (so I'm not voting to close this one of course), but a Google search for "encrypt in javascript decrypt in php" is showing some promising results.  If the "encryption" doesn't need to be even *remotely* strong then perhaps a basic Base-64 encoding would do the trick for the majority of your cases.  Since the goal isn't to actually protect anything, but just to have what looks like gibberish to most users.

Comment: many thanks :) .. I already googled, and found multiple approaches, so I thought I ask for advice which to use.. but I think I'll give base-64 a try